# Composition of 2 monotonic functions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Let $f$ be a monotonic function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ be a monotonic function $g:[c,d]\rightarrow[a,b]$. Show that $f\circ g$ is monotonic

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Let $*$ represent either $<$ or $>$, depending on the direction of the monotonicity in each case. Then
$$x*y\implies g(x)*g(y)\implies f\circ g(x)*f\circ g(y)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused here. What does ∗ really represent? Is it a function's operator?

Comment: As I said it is either "lesser than" or "greater than". (This notation is not standard at all).