# Monotone functions analyze

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Let $f,g : \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$. Suppose that $f\circ g$ is a strictly monotone growing function and $f$ is a strictly monotone decreasing function.

Can I conclude from those details that $g$ is a strictly monotone decreasing function?

Comment: When exists apply the monotone $f^{-1}$ to the monotone $f\circ g$. [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246758/composition-of-2-monotonic-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Without adding "strictly" in front of "monotone", then no. $f(x) = 1$ is both monotone increasing and monotone decreasing, and no matter what $g$ is, the same will apply to $f\circ g$.

Comment: Wherever mentioned "montone" I meant to say "strictly monotone". Edited accordingly. What would be the answer in that case?